# Date difference (in days) using a cutoff value in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning Spark, and I am trying to create a column of the difference in days between a date and a cutoff value.

Here is some data along with my solution using pandas.

```
lst = ['2018-11-21',
        '2018-11-01',
        '2018-10-09',
        '2018-11-23',
        '2018-11-08',
        '2018-10-06',
        '2018-11-27',
        '2018-10-07',
        '2018-10-23',
        '2018-11-02']

d = pd.DataFrame({'event':np.arange(len(lst)),'ts':lst})
d['ts'] = d['ts'].apply(pd.to_datetime) # only needed because I have alist of strings

d['new_ts'] = d.ts - (d.ts.max() - pd.to_timedelta(15, unit='d'))
```

Unfortunately I can't find a way to adapt this logic to pyspark. I think the issue is in the subtraction of a static date that is not part of the DataFrame.

Assuming that df is the "Spark version" of the above dataset "d", here is one of the things I tried:

```
calculator = udf(lambda x: datediff(datediff(date_sub(max(x),30),x)))
c = df.withColumn('Recency',calculator(col('ts')))
```

However, he followings give me a long error
c.select(col('Recency')).show(1)
c.show(1)

Thanks in advance to everyone who is gonna help.

Comment: If I get it well, the cutoff value is the max of the column Date?

Comment: @KhalilFall, No the cutoff value is some days before the max of the col Date. The solution below is the one I have implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is:

- Compute max date.
- Subtract given number of days to get cutoff date.
- Find difference in days from cutoff date.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["2018-11-21"],["2018-11-01"],["2018-10-09"],["2018-11-23"],["2018-11-08"],["2018-10-06"],["2018-11-27"],["2018-10-07"],["2018-10-23"],["2018-11-02"]], schema=["ts"])

df = df.withColumn("ts", F.to_date("ts", "yyyy-MM-dd"))

cutoff_dt = df.select(F.date_sub(F.max("ts"), 15).alias("cutoff_dt")).first().asDict()["cutoff_dt"]

df = df.withColumn("new_ts", F.datediff("ts", F.lit(cutoff_dt)))

df.show(truncate=False)

+----------+------+
|ts        |new_ts|
+----------+------+
|2018-11-21|9     |
|2018-11-01|-11   |
|2018-10-09|-34   |
|2018-11-23|11    |
|2018-11-08|-4    |
|2018-10-06|-37   |
|2018-11-27|15    |
|2018-10-07|-36   |
|2018-10-23|-20   |
|2018-11-02|-10   |
+----------+------+
```